# What is the recommended approach for controller servlets which deal with multiple urls?

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have been following the netbeans ecommerce tutorial and they [introduced a ControllerServlet](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/page-views-controller.html) which they setup to deal with multiple URLs.

However the way they do this is basically to have a big `if then else if` statement:

```
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();

    // if category page is requested
    if (userPath.equals("/category")) {
        // TODO: Implement category request

    // if cart page is requested
    } else if (userPath.equals("/viewCart")) {
        // TODO: Implement cart page request

        userPath = "/cart";

    // if checkout page is requested
    } else if (userPath.equals("/checkout")) {
        // TODO: Implement checkout page request

    // if user switches language
    } else if (userPath.equals("/chooseLanguage")) {
        // TODO: Implement language request

    }
```

Is this really the recommended way of handling multiple URLs in a single servlet?  This approach seems horrible and difficult to manage.

Or am I missing some obvious way of handling this cleanly?

Comment: This is indeed horrible. A real decent front controller is however much more complex. They apparently wanted to keep it simple for starters. I would for this tutorial rather have used separate servlets (since Servlet 3.0 it's really easy to register servlets as standalone mini-controllers by `@WebServlet` annotation without any XML configuration), instead of giving a misleading introduction into "Front Controller" design. See also this related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications

Comment: @BalusC thanks.  I agree that they should have just done one servlet per url in the samples, and the answer linked reconfirmed my initial ideas about addressing the issues.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an MVC framework like Stripes or Spring MVC, which handles this for you (and much more). In those frameworks, you configure a single servlet to intercept all the requests to a given URL pattern (*.action for example), and this servlet dispatches to appropriate actions based on annotations and/or naming conventions and/or configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  yes I am aware of Spring MVC (which I agree is a much better way of handling it) but this is for a course in which were taught to use servlets, so I really wanted to know what the best practice was for plain vanilla servlets.

Comment: If you use plain servlets, then have one servlet per URL (or group of URLs), or reimplement your own MVC framework. But there are already dozens of them, so I would go this way.

Comment: Yes thanks.  I'll probably implement a single servlet which has an AbstractFactory to generate a handler for the particular URL rather than take a dependency on a 3rd party library, but point out in the report for my coursework that reinventing this wheel is probably a bad idea and point out the available frameworks which could make this simpler.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **ServletFilter** and configure your web.xml in the following manner to redirect the client requests to the appropriate destination controller.

The  would make keep changing for the different user-paths from your code snippet above.

Using this approach you could send multiple urls to the same(or multiple) filters based on your requirement.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.project.my.MYclass</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than what I currently have, which is annotations on a class which defines which urls it will handle, but all urls are still handled by the same method in the class?  which method in the specified class (`com.project.my.MYclass`) will be called when the filter matches

Comment: I did not see the annotations in the link (or code snippet) you have provided above so it appeared to me that a simple if and else condition blocks were used to redirect the url. If it is the same class which all the requests then you probably need a Factory pattern in place for the implementation to promote low coupling.